# Jquery table: customize seanmacisaac table / insert tbody into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, html-table

I am trying to adjust a Jquery sort-able, searchable table set up by seanmacisaac
Ref: http://www.seanjmacisaac.com/projects/code/tablesort/#index-member-4

How do I set the tbody height to a fixed value. Also allowing vertical scroll (overflow-y)?

```
<table class="table-sort table-sort-search table-sort-show-search-count">

<thead>
<tr><th class="table-sort">head1</th><th class="table-sort">head2</th><th class="table-sort">head3</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td>1-1</td><td>1-2</td><td>1-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2-1</td><td>2-2</td><td>2-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>3-1</td><td>3-2</td><td>3-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4-1</td><td>4-2</td><td>4-3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the table into a div :

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:500px;width:100%">
    <table></table> // with any number of row
</div>
```

Put the css into a class and add a class to the container div

Comment: Mathieu, for the simple solution you are correct. But sean's table add codes to the user table (i think that's what it is doing for what i have tried). I have tried adding div between header and data, when I run it, the div somehow is before the <table>.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll only the data section of the table not with headers then you should make html like:

```
<div class="header-table" style="width:100%">
<table class="header"></table>
</div>
<div class="table-data" style="overflow:auto;height:500px;width:100%">
<table class="data"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Mayank, thanks for the suggestion. I already knew that using div to separate the header and data can do the trick (after researches).

But I want more than just a simple table, it needs to be sortable, searchable and vertically scrollable.

With seanmaissac's table, it does 2 out of 3 already. The difficult part is that his table design is somehow generated with Javascript (the js file overwrites the normal table and adds new codes [no problem]). But it doesn't like using div to split the header and data. It somehow removes the div to be before the table codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the header fixed while scrolling, for simple tables, I create a two separate tables: 
the first for the header and the second in a div with fixed height and overflow-y:auto, just for the tbody.
Not that elegant but just do the job.

Don't know where this table will be but I think you should use a paginator for 100+ rows tables...

If the problem is sorting data and paginate I'd give jqGrid a chance: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: mauoftheclouds, thanks for the reply. This is the closest to what I want so far, but it is possible to have the search window as a search bar? It is much more user friendly to not have to click for search everytime.

Comment: Do you mean something like the example (in the page I linked before) under Advanced -> Search Big Sets?

Comment: no wrong, but not what i am after. I have added some information to the question (which i think is the key to the solution). If you can take some time and take a look, please.